# Setting multiple values to a variable depending on the situation

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to make a Server command in which it would show you some information about a server, and that includes the server owner. But when the owner's offline it throws an error, and instead of that I want it to say "Not Found" in the embed. The code I tried seems to be completely wrong from what I've seen online:

```
let owner = message.guild.owner;
if(!owner) let owner = 'Not Found';
```

Uh... Yeah. I would like to know how I can set a different value to something depending on, in this case, if the owner is online/found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```js
let owner = message.guild.owner;
if(!owner) owner = 'Not Found';
```

`owner` is now visible in your whole command code. To change it when there is no owner you can just use the name of the variable and set a new value for it.